# Encrypt / Decrypt plain text in 2022

Tags: dart

I need to encrypt plain text and send it as plain text via JSON
I also need to receive the plain text that was encrypted from JSON and decrypt it to the original plain text.

All examples I can find suggest using encrypt 5.0.1
I can see how they encrypt the text and decrypt the encrypted text but there is no example where you can actually decrypt the plain encrypted text back to the original text.

String Encryption package is not supported anymore and Flutter will not accept it as a valid package anymore.

Could you please give me an idea where to look to solve the issue?

Comment: What do you mean by [no example](https://pub.dev/packages/encrypt#usage)?

Comment: "I can see how they encrypt the text and decrypt the encrypted text" sounds exactly like "decrypt the plain encrypted text back to the original text." How are these different?